# C void pointer calculation in gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Today I spotted a Linux kernel patch in ext4 tree.

> A missing cast means that when we are truncating a file which is less
>   than 60 bytes, we don't trunate the wrong area of memory, and in fact
>   we can end up truncating the next inode in the inode table, or worse
>   yet, some other kernel data structure.
>
> - Addresses-Coverity-Id: #751987
> - Signed-off-by: "Theodore Ts'o"
> - Cc: stable@vger.kernel.org

---

```
 fs/ext4/inline.c | 8 +++++---
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

diff --git a/fs/ext4/inline.c b/fs/ext4/inline.c
index c417e52..ed29e72 100644
--- a/fs/ext4/inline.c
+++ b/fs/ext4/inline.c
@@ -1928,9 +1928,11 @@ void ext4_inline_data_truncate(struct inode *inode, int *has_inline)
                }

                /* Clear the content within i_blocks. */
-               if (i_size < EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE)
-                       memset(ext4_raw_inode(&is.iloc)->i_block + i_size, 0,
-                                       EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE - i_size);
+               if (i_size < EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE) {
+                       void *p = (void *) ext4_raw_inode(&is.iloc)->i_block;
+                       memset(p + i_size, 0,
+                              EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE - i_size);
+               }

                EXT4_I(inode)->i_inline_size = i_size <
                                        EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE ?
```

Note. `i_block's` type is array of `__le32`.  `i_size`'s type is long long.
My question is: is that the old version do calculation based on 4 bytes and new version does calculation based on 1 byte?
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "*`i_block`'s type is `u32`*" - Not according to http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L650  According to that page, the type is "array of u32".

Comment: You mean `i_block` is an array of `u32`, right? It matters a lot here.

Comment: The patch isn't valid C, as performing pointer arithmetic on `void *` typed pointer are not defined by the C Standard. The patch should have casted to `char *` instead.

Comment: @alk: Except that the Linux Kernel is not written in C, it's written in C with a pile of gcc extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's take the original code, and make the type of it very explicit to readers. If we do that, then we are looking at the following two pieces of code:

1. The original code:

   ```
   __le32 *p = (void *) ext4_raw_inode(&is.iloc)->i_block;
   memset(p + i_size, 0, EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE - i_size);
   ```
2. The new code:

   ```
   void *p = (void *) ext4_raw_inode(&is.iloc)->i_block;
   memset(p + i_size, 0, EXT4_MIN_INLINE_DATA_SIZE - i_size);
   ```

Now, it's fairly clear that the value of `p + i_size` will be different depending on the type of `p`, which this patch has fixed.

Comment: I feel it is worth mentioning that performing arithmetisc on `void` pointers isn't valid C, but a gcc extension.

Comment: And said arithmetic just operates as if it was char * (i.e., it advances the address by i_size bytes here)